# How to combine Retrofit and LocalDB requests and give result to RecyclerView in MVVM?

Tags: java, android, mvvm, rx-java, android-livedata

I want to get result from retrofit, if it is possible, send this data to recyclerview adapter like livedata and save in local DB. If retrofit couldn't get result data, it should load from local database. My code in MainActivity:

```
private void initRecyclerView() {

    recyclerView = binding.rvTasks;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewModel.getTasks().observe(this, tasks -> {
        adapter.setTaskCollection(tasks);
    });
}
```

Then, in MainActivityVeiwModel:

```
public LiveData<List<Task>> getTasks() {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(retrofitApi.getTasks()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnError(throwable -> dataStorage.getTaskCollection())
    );
```

And DataStorage:

```
public Flowable<List<Task>> getTaskCollection() {
    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Task> entry : localDatabase.getTaskCollention().entrySet())
        taskList.add(entry.getValue());
    return Flowable
            .just(taskList);
}
```

If network is connected, retrofit loading data, but I can't save it by subscribe cause "LiveDataReactiveStreams cannot ba applied to Disposable". If network not available -> FATAL EXCEPTION: main LiveData does not handle errors. Errors from publishers should be handled upstream and propagated as state.

Comment: you can use MutableLiveData. make the network call in getTasks() and when result comes set value in mutable liveata and you can observe mutable livedata for changes.

Comment: @AmitTiwary not a problem to observe LiveData if retrofit request is success. I can't combine it with database if network not available

Answer (score 0):

You can directly store data in db. If you use Room(an ORM for SQLite), It can emit livedata. You just need to set an observer in your activity. When the DB changes, The changes will be automatically propagated to your UI

Comment: 1)Can you show an example? I'll implemented Room 2)Main question - how to combine? How store data? LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher take only Publisher and I can't change or handle errors after retrofit request